# how to have multiple index in a table of laravel migration

Tags: laravel

I have product table with this migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->bigInteger('price');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('images');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->integer('viewCount')->default(0);
        $table->integer('commentCount')->default(0);
        $table->integer('stockCount')->default(0);
        $table->integer('sailedCount')->default(0);

        $table->boolean('specialSail')->default(false);

        $table->integer('size_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('sizes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('color_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I want in same time 3 colume(code,size_id,color_id) be index but I have a product by same name and same code but different size.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: Your price must be a decimal value? then change `$table->bigInteger('price');` to `$table->decimal('price', 25, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `InnoDB` storage engine, then you don't need to create index for that. `InnoDB` will create indexes automatically.

You can edit your `/config/database.php` file, search for mysql entry and change:

```
'engine' => null,
 // Change it to
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

This saves you from adding `$table->engine = "InnoDB";` for each of your Schema's.

You can create multiple index by :

```
$table->string('slug')->index();
$table->string('name')->index();
```

Or,

```
$table->index(['slug', 'name']);
```

Comment: The syntax `$table->index('slug', 'name');` is wrong, it will create only an index for `slug`. To create a compound index of 2 columns, the syntax is `$table->index(['slug', 'name']);`. [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes).